# How to restrict Button working like Cursor in 3D map Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

Hello Everybody I'm working on a Soccer Game which is based on Kinect Movmement and the Csharp language.

I have a UI Button and I make it like circle under canvas 
that canvas found in 3D model which is the stadium.

The button working like a cursor and it translate by script which synchronises between the right hand of the player which is forward the kinect and the cursor which is original button.

okay all this istriction working good and perfect, just one thing when I'm moving from other scene which is 2D to this scene which is 3D I found the cursor moving in this position `-12125.34 , -3132.932 , -1`,
while it was in the precedent Scene which is 2D in this position 
`-616 , 288 , -1`

if you don't understand me just think you moving you right hand forward the kinect and you moving an object by the same hand 
the code which I wrote for that istriction is that

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HandController : MonoBehaviour {

    public static HandController Instance;

    private Vector2 initialPosition;//body initial position 

    public GameObject cursorObject;
    private bool cursorEnter = false;

    private float delay ;
    private float timeing;
    private float firstContactTime;
    private string[] flagsTable = new string [] {
        "Tunisia", "Maroco","Austria", "Belgium", "cameroon",
        "cote_d_ivoire", "Egypt","france", "guini", "jordan",
        "liberia", "madagascar","mali", "mauritius", "moldova",
        "romanie", "Slovakie","Spain", "United_kingdom", "Vanuatu",
        "polgne"
    };


    private bool checkingFlagsTableDone = false;
    public static bool flagsFound = false;
    public static string countryChoosingName = "";
    public Button btnSelected;
    public string buttonSelected = "";
    public Button myCursor;
    public Image myCursorImage;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;

    }
    void Start () {

        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.root.gameObject);
       // var vertExtent = Camera.main.camera.orthographicSize;
        //var horzExtent = vertExtent * Screen.width / Screen.height;

    }
    public int offstX= 937;
    public int offstY= 520;

    bool isInited=false;

    void Update() {
        float initialXposition = transform.localPosition.x;
        float initialYposition = transform.localPosition.y;
        float nextXposition=0;
        float nextYposition=0;

        KinectManager manager = KinectManager.Instance;

        if (DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders != null)
        {
            if (manager.Player1Calibrated && isInited == false)
            {
                isInited = true;
                nextXposition = transform.localPosition.x;
                nextYposition = transform.localPosition.y;
                if (initialXposition != nextXposition && initialYposition != nextYposition)
                {
                   // Debug.Log("I moved the cursor the the initial pisition");
                }
                //else
                   // Debug.Log("Sorry I didn't translate the cursor");
            } else if (manager.Player1Calibrated && isInited == true)
            {
                float XvalueAre = DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.x * 192.0f + 184430.4f + offstX;
                float YvalueAre = DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.y *108.0f + 58832.1f + offstY;


            Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(XvalueAre - offstX, YvalueAre - offstY);
                transform.position = new Vector3(newPos.x,newPos.y,-1);
            }
         }
        else { Debug.Log("Erreur remplir joints colliders "); }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////Delay Time Over Button /////////////////////////////////////////////


        if (cursorEnter == true) {
            delay = Time.time - firstContactTime;
            //Debug.Log("waiting time is => " + delay);
            myCursorImage .fillAmount =  1 - (delay / 3) ;
            if (delay > 3) {

                if (currentBtn != null) { 
                    CheckOnOverButtonName(currentBtn.name);

                    Debug.Log("Button Name => " + currentBtn.name);
                    if (flagsFound == true)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("the country choose is => " + countryChoosingName);
                        currentBtn.onClick.Invoke();
                        myCursorImage.fillAmount = 1;
                        cursorEnter = false;
                        buttonSelected = countryChoosingName; 
                    }
                    Debug.Log("the country choose is => " + currentBtn.name);
                    currentBtn.onClick.Invoke();
                    myCursorImage.fillAmount = 1;
                    cursorEnter=false;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    Button currentBtn;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        firstContactTime = Time.time;
        cursorEnter = true;
        currentBtn = coll.GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        cursorEnter = false; 
        flagsFound = false;
        countryChoosingName = "";
        checkingFlagsTableDone = false;
    }


    void CheckOnOverButtonName(string buttonName)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < flagsTable.Length ; i++ ){
            if (string.Compare(flagsTable[i],buttonName) == 0) {
                flagsFound = true;
                countryChoosingName = flagsTable[i];
                if (i == flagsTable.Length) {
                    checkingFlagsTableDone = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the text you wrote quite heavily to make it a bit more clear but I'm still having trouble understanding what's going on... You have a UI Button that moves, in 2d, syncronously to your Kinect Movement? Also, what do you mean by "istriction"?

Comment: I assume in 2D you've used orthographical camera which has the same size independently of the depth. When switching into 3D you have to consider that position further away from the camera get's bigger deviation.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I slove the Problem after using Mathf.Clamp

```
   float XvalueAre = DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.x * 192.0f + 184430.4f + offstX;
                    float YvalueAre = DepthImageViewer.Instance.jointColliders[11].transform.localPosition.y * 108.0f + 58832.1f  + offstY;

                    float x = Mathf.Clamp(XvalueAre, 0.0f,1024.0f);
                    float y = Mathf.Clamp(YvalueAre, 0.0f,768.0f);
                    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, -1);
```